# How to set a variable from the result of a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something like the following:

```
select value1 from Table1 where id='123';
```

Result = 'foo'

I then manually type in the result 'foo' to set the variable @v1:

```
SET @v1='foo';
```

I then use that variable to calculate a few other queries.

```
select value2 from Table2 where table2Id=@v1;
select value3 from Table3 where table3Id=@v1;
select value4 from Table4 where table4Id=@v1;
```

Is it possible to set @v1 from the result of the first query qithout having to type it in? Like

```
SET @v1 = select value1 from Table1 where id='123';
```

Comment: Why not a subquery? `select value2 from Table2 where table2Id= (select value1 from Table1 where id='123')`

Comment: SUbquery? Why not a JOIN?

Comment: Why not Zoidberg? Multiple ways to the same result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables:

```
select Table2.value2 from Table2 left join Table1 on Table2.table2Id = Table1.id
```

No problem doing that for your other tables (Table3, Table4) just as well. If you want the results of all these queries as one table, use UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `JOIN` as

```
select
t2.value2 from Table2 t2
join Table1 t1 on t1.value1 = t2.table2Id
where t1.id = '123'
```

and this applies to all the tables with the joining clause.

Answer (score 0):

declare  @v1 varchar(200) set @vi =(select top 1 value1 from Table1 where id='123'
select value2 from Table2 where table2Id=@v1